# Using the gradle task DSL within custom TaskActions?

Tags: plugins, groovy, gradle

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    String property = "default"

```
@TaskAction
def grailsAppClean() {
    delete fileTree {
      ...
    }
    exec {
      ...
    }
}
```

And in my plugin, I have this:

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.task('myTask', type: MyTask)
}
```

When I call the task directly from an external gradle script, or use `type: MyTask`, I get the following error:

`Could not find method fileTree()...`

Can I use the built-in tasks this way via the DSL? If not, how can I manually invoke `FileTree` and `Exec`? I'd love to be able to use the DSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can write a script plugin rather than a binary plugin. If you want to stick to a binary plugin, you can get the DSL syntax with:

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.configure(project) {
        delete fileTree {
            ...
        }
        exec {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few syntax bits that you can't get because they are implemented with a Grooyy AST transform. The one that comes to mind is the `task foo(...)` syntax. Also you have to repeat the `project.configure(project)` in every method. You can abstract it away into a helper method though.

Comment: By "script plugin", you mean defining the task directly within the build.gradle for the plugin? I have a number of discrete tasks, so this might get cluttered.

Comment: No, I mean another .gradle file that gets applied with `apply from: "path/to/foo.gradle"` or `apply from: "http://..."`. That's what we call a _script plugin_.